# Have I lost my my wallet funds

Tags: go-ethereum, ethers.js, etherscan, ethereum-wallet-dapp

So I transferred my eth from trust into compound.pw but when I go back to it it shows my balance as 0.. my friend who is helping me on this journey has said as I didn’t put £500 in to start with it won’t show up.. however when I go through my etherscan it shows that Iv transferred my eth out hence why I don’t have any showing.. have I been scammed or not

Comment: The official site for Compound is `https://app.compound.finance`. It is very likely you have been scammed.